# How to search Go documentation?

Tags: go

The documentation is great, but sometimes it is hard to find a specific keyword. For instance, searching for `Next()`results in this page http://golang.org/search?q=next%28%29 which is not very helpful. Is there a better way to search the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rob Pike wrote the perfect tool for this. Install it with `go`:

```
go get code.google.com/p/rspace.cmd/doc
```

You can then say `doc next` (or `doc Next`) and get an awesome list of `Next` functions in all packages, along with their documentations and signature. If you know the name of the package, you can say `doc sql next` or `doc sql.next`. You can even pass `-url` to get URL of that documentation online, or `-src` to get file name and line number for the implementation of that symbol.

You can access package documentation (documentation that appears at the top of a package’s page and doesn’t belong to any of its items) with `-pkg`: `doc -pkg json`.

`doc` searches for everything and you can limit it to only search for functions, interfaces, variables, etc. Run it without arguments to get the docs.

It’s such a great tool. Keep it close when you’re writing in Go.

Comment: On OS X, you could also use [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) which is not limited to Go and is very streamlined.

Comment: I tried to download but I got this error: `go: missing Mercurial command. See http://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package code.google.com/p/rspace.cmd/doc: exec: "hg": executable file not found in %PATH%` Then I installed Mercurial but I still get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you’ve installed Mercurial, it’s not in your `$PATH`. Add it’s directory to your `$PATH` or put a symlink to its binary in one of your `$PATH` directories. FYI, Mercurial’s binary file is `hg`.

Comment: I added `C:\Program Files\Mercurial` to my Python path in Windows and I executed `go get code.google.com/p/rspace.cmd/doc` and it went through without an error. But I cannot use `doc`. I get the error `'doc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Maybe this does not work on windows.

Comment: No, it should work. So you’ve installed `doc` successfully, you now just have to add it to your `$PATH` too, just like you did with Mercurial. I don’t know where is `$GOROOT` in Windows. Wherever it is, it has a `bin` directory which includes `doc` executable (and executables of other Go programs). Add that to your `$PATH` and you’re good to go.

Comment: Thanks, @Mostafa - I'll ask a new question about this. I have both in my `GOPATH` but it is not working: `C:\Users\A\Desktop\go;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\Users\A\Desktop\go\bin`

Comment: @Zeynel You need to add `C:\Users\A\Desktop\go\bin` to your `PATH` variable, not your `GOPATH`.

Answer (score 4):

- Do not include the parenthesis in the query.
- Search only for exported identifiers by capitalization of the first letter.

Search for [`Next`](http://golang.org/search?q=Next) gains a much better result set IMO.

BTW, the old techiques are still going strong as well ;-)

```
jnml@fsc-r630:~/go/src/pkg$ egrep -nr '^func \([^)]+\) Next\(' *
archive/tar/reader.go:42:func (tr *Reader) Next() (*Header, error) {
bytes/buffer.go:273:func (b *Buffer) Next(n int) []byte {
container/ring/ring.go:26:func (r *Ring) Next() *Ring {
container/list/list.go:31:func (e *Element) Next() *Element {
database/sql/fakedb_test.go:658:func (rc *rowsCursor) Next(dest []driver.Value) error {
database/sql/sql.go:1300:func (rs *Rows) Next() bool {
debug/dwarf/entry.go:310:func (r *Reader) Next() (*Entry, error) {
net/smtp/auth.go:75:func (a *plainAuth) Next(fromServer []byte, more bool) ([]byte, error) {
net/smtp/auth.go:99:func (a *cramMD5Auth) Next(fromServer []byte, more bool) ([]byte, error) {
net/textproto/pipeline.go:36:func (p *Pipeline) Next() uint {
reflect/all_test.go:3390:func (x *exhaustive) Next() bool {
text/scanner/scanner.go:302:func (s *Scanner) Next() rune {
jnml@fsc-r630:~/go/src/pkg$
```

Comment: The search field accepts regular expressions, so parentheses have special meaning. I could not use the slashes there though, it escapes them.

Answer (score 2):

This works pretty well:

```
func ([(][^)]+[)] )?[N]ext
```

If you want case-insensitive search, use

```
func ([(][^)]+[)] )?next
```